# Combining Composite and Strategy

Tags: design-patterns

I am looking for an example showing how to combine this 2 design patterns (Strategy and Composite). I know how to use Strategy, but Composite is not enough clear for me, so I can't really see how to combine them. Does someone have example or smthg?
Cheers

Comment: Why do you want to combine them? Do you have a logical/business problem that requires this?

Comment: Patterns used for solving problems, not for creating patterns combinations. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ok this is a way to do that out of the blue (in pseudo Java code):

```
interface TradingStrategy {
    void buy();
    void sell();   
}

class HedgingLongTermStrategy implements TradingStrategy {
    void buy() { /* TODO: */ };
    void sell() { /* TODO: */ };   
}

class HighFreqIntradayStrategy implements TradingStrategy {
    void buy() { /* TODO: */ };
    void sell() { /* TODO: */ };   
}

class CompositeTradingStrategy extends ArrayList<TradingStrategy> implements TradingStrategy {
    void buy() {
       for (TradingStrategy strategy : this) {
           strategy.buy();
       }
    }
    void sell() {
       for (TradingStrategy strategy : this) {
           strategy.sell();
       }
    }
}

// sample code
TradingStrategy composite = new CompositeTradingStrategy();
composite.add(new HighFreqIntradayStrategy());  
composite.add(new HedgingLongTermStrategy());
composite.buy();
```